# Building parameters with js object

Tags: jquery

This is similar to a previous question I asked but I'm not sure if my intention was clear enough. So I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfzqaf2u/6/) and provide more details of what I'm looking to achieve.

I'm trying to build a hash which I can then send via an ajax request to perform a query, the hash would look like this `category = { "gender": '', "styles": [] };`

There are a few things I would like to happen:

1) A user can only select `Mens` or `Womens` at any one time, causing the other option to become unclickable (the clicked option should always be in the JS object).

2) if a user has `Mens` selected already and then clicks on the same option then that option becomes unchecked and the `womens` option then becomes clickable and vice versa.

3) When a type (so `Mountain Bike` etc) is selected it as added to the styles array, and when that type is unchecked it is then removed.

With my jsfiddle the `li` class `active` is not being updated (even though the parameter class appears) and I can't seem to grab the closest label to enable the switch statement to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be made a lot simpler than you are attempting to.

Firstly, to solve points 1 and 2 use a radio input - you get that behaviour by default. To meet point 3 you can use `map()` to create an array of the checked options. To make this simpler you can add `class` attributes on the inputs to make their identification much easier.

Also note that your HTML as it stands is invalid as you have not given a `name` attribute to any of your `input` elements and you cannot have an `input` inside an `a` element.

Finally, you should always hook to the `change` event on radio and checkbox elements to cater for people who navigate the web via their keyboard.

With all that in mind, here's a much simpler working example:

```js
var category = {
  "gender": '',
  "styles": []
};

$(".multiselect-container input").on('change', function(event) {
  category.gender = $('.gender:checked').val();
  category.styles = $('.styles:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
  console.log(category);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
  <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group genders">
    <label><b>Gender</b>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="Mens" name="gender" class="gender" />Mens
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="radio" value="Womens" name="gender" class="gender" />Womens
    </label>
  </li>

  <li class="multiselect-item multiselect-group types">
    <label><b>Type</b>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Mountain Bike" class="styles" name="styles" />Mountain Bike
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Hybrid" class="styles" name="styles" />Hybrid
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Road" class="styles" name="styles" />Road
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wow, that is ridiculously simpler, i may have been constraining myself then as the html that is generated is a result of https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect i will see if i can change the html then to use radio buttons instead, thank you so much for pointing all this out

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Personally I would find another plugin to use - I can see several issues with that one already.

Comment: any suggestions please ? and what issues do you see ?

Comment: Sorry, none off the top of my head. I'd have thought a quick google should find some though.

Comment: Ok but what problems do you see, just so I can not have the same issues with another plugin, thanks

Comment: Or am I better off not using a plugin and just style myself?

Comment: I'd go with building it yourself for something this specific.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help :-)